# What's the best jQuery clockpick plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, clock

I need a clockpicker. I would like a jQuery plugin because I use this library in my application. I need any plugin that might be for minute selections. It shouldn't be only for defined ranges. If anyone knows a clockpick with these features, I thank you.

Please help me, I have a very good plugin for other cases, but for defined ranges of hours, I would like an analog clock, if it's possible.

Comment: try some from http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/time-picker

Comment: Sorry, this is a subjective question, and most likely will be voted to be closed within the next few minutes. See the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) ("What kind of questions should I not ask here?")

Answer (score 0):

While not an analog clock, I've found [Trent Richardson' Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker/) addon to JQuery UI datepicker excellent.

It allows you to filter time range and set steps as well in the picking. You can use it standalone just to select a time or with datepicker to give a combined solution. Give it a shot.

[Here are some demos of ways to use it as well.](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

how about TimeEntry plugin.

http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

it's very good one. i use for my apps and works great.